# Laravel 5 eloquent not storing special characters in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, utf-8

I am using laravel 5.2 and here are my database configuration settings:

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

I have also tried `'utf8_unicode_ci'` as collation but its also not working.

Use case: This is the text I am trying to insert:

> $str = "Après 9 mois passés dans le"

but this is storing:

```
Apr&egrave;s 9 mois pass&eacute;s dans le
```

Comment: Was a type issue

Comment: I see. Check that you're not doing `htmlentities` on the text anywhere or that you're not receiving it like that from the source (I'm guessing a form?)

Comment: I used `htmlentities` but still its not working

Comment: Make sure you are **not** doing `htmlentities`. Also do a `dd(..)` on the text to see if it's actually being received like that. If it's coming from a form it might be converted to html entities before the submit

Comment: Worse case you can do `html_entity_decode(...)` on the text before inserting it

Comment: @apokryfos, `html_entity_decode` is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MahaDev how did you resolve this? what was the type issue can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing there is the text being replaced with [HTML entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) this usually is the result of text coming directly from an HTML source (either a form with text that was previously converted to `htmlentities` or an other source).

The ideal solution here is to ensure that the text is not received as HTML entity encoded, however if this is not an option (which it very often is not), you can use:

```
 $decoded = html_entity_decode($text);
```

to decode the entities into their actual characters before you insert them.

A bit of trivia:

You don't actually need to encode all characters to their corresponding entities to display on HTML as long as you're properly sending Unicode text. This is why PHP has 2 different functions [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) where the first function only encodes what is necessary to encode in order to not break HTML (those 5 characters listed in the manual, <, >, &, " and ') while the second one encodes everything based on the linked table.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Database.php` insert :

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

This should allow you from saving the string in the format you want.

And please make sure that your MySQL is set to `utf8`

Comment: try to go to the table, for each column change the property to` utf8mb4_unicode_ci  ` .. if this didn't help, then you have a problem in your IDE

Comment: "html entities" is not something that MySQL deals with.